# Is there a popular software that creates HTML(5) Forms from MySQL tables

Tags: php, html, forms

Recently I had to work with Microsoft Access and I noticed that Access offers a set of easy-to use-tools. Most notably it can create input forms - based on the underlying tables - within seconds.

As creating input forms (and validating the input with Javascript and PHP) is one of the *most common tasks* of any web developer, I thought there must be some easy software to create these.

**Q: Is there a standard/preferred software for (php) web developers to create and validate HTML input forms based on the SQL-table-structure?**

So the idea is:

- MySQL table with all fields already existing
- A nice peace of software should now create the HTML5 Form based on the table-fields
- A javascript/jQuery-script will also be generated that validates the user input
- Moreover it also creates php code to "hard-validate" the input

While doing my research, I found one software that seems to do what I want: http://www.scriptcase.net/

However, the software is expensive and I don't know anything about its quality.

Another example is http://www.phpform.org/. While it seems to be a quick way to create HTML forms, you can't load data from your database or get any PHP code.

Or: What's your approach to creating input forms?

Comment: How many tables do you have?!

Comment: @screenmutt this question shouldn't matter. A possible solution should work with any table. Just like in MS Access: With a few clicks, drags and drops I can create a simple form based on one ore many underlying tables.

Comment: Just more of a comment on the nature of the question. I am wondering what your motivation is for this? Creating forms is pretty easy. You could even write a script to do it.

Comment: @screenmutt well, you are right, it is easy. However it is time consuming. I'm starting to work on an admin interface and I will have to create at least 10 HTML Forms, the validation routine and it would be neat to just click a button and get the full form.

Comment: Are you locked into PHP? Ruby on Rails has generators which do this.

Comment: @screenmutt I have access to ruby on rails, never used it though. What generators do you suggest?

Comment: First off. I am going to say, I came to Rails because of Ruby. I am a little prejudiced because I think Ruby is the best programming language that will ever be invented. That said... Rails includes default generators which will create a model, controller, and view based upon your migration, which is a way of describing the mysql database. (Rails Generators)[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any software that would be able to map a database table to a webform in a way that the user would want to see it, but consider checking out a framework like Symfony2. It doesn't automatically convert anything, but it does really strip down on the amount of work needed while still giving you full control over things like rendering, validation, and relations between various database tables.

Comment: The correct answer is doctrine of symfony, which includes doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few options.

- [Formitable](http://formitable.sourceforge.net/)
- [A Tutorial, doesn't include validation](http://davidwalsh.name/html-mysql-php)